# NodeJS How to encrypt (AES algorithm) data using crypto-js, or crypto package encoded in UTF8 using custom keysize, iv, mode and padding

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am working with an API that require me to encrypt data before sending it with custom parameters and I am unable to get a good response from the server.

I want to be sure this code is correct for this operation because my response from the server says it's unable to process my request. `"Error Processing Request"`

Below is a the sample code I got from the Postman collection.

```
CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');



AES_ENCRYPT = function(){
  var key = "1234567";
  var iv  = "7654321";
  key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
  iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);
  const encryptData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(rawData), 
  key,
    {
         keySize: 128 / 8,
         iv: iv,
         mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
         padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
 return encryptData;
}
```

From my experience when encryption is done we get a string in return but in this case I am not getting a string and I have tried `encryptData.toString()` on the return value but no luck.

I want to know if I can do this same operation using another node package to get the right result or do this the right way using same `crypto-js` package.

Comment: The crypto JS chooses the type of encryption based on the key input and *the idiot that did the API design* will *derive a key* rather than use it directly if you pass a string: "CryptoJS supports AES-128, AES-192, and AES-256. It will pick the variant by the size of the key you pass in. If you use a passphrase, then it will generate a 256-bit key.". If you want to be compatible with a server then you need a *protocol specification*. Ask for it! Just "AES" or even "AES/CBC" is **not** enough.

Comment: Oh, wait, you do encode the key to bytes. Hmm. Better have a look at the answer of tbking where the key and IV are explicitly put in buffers. Your key is too small for AES, so *something* is going terribly wrong with it (unless the above code is not indicative in the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use built-in module, [`crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) as it is easier to use and have more resources online.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var iv = 'some 16 byte iv';
var key = 'some 16 byte long key';
var plainText = 'some plain text';
var algo = 'aes-128-cbc'; // we are using 128 bit here because of the 16 byte key. use 256 is the key is 32 byte.

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', new Buffer(key), new Buffer(iv));
var encrypted = cipher.update(plainText, 'utf-8', 'base64'); // `base64` here represents output encoding
encrypted += cipher.final('base64');

console.log('encrypted'); //returns encrypted data in base64 encoding
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for the suggestion. I've added comments to the code to add context to the answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Please leave the "idiot" I'm also pissed with the API in general. It has very bad documentation plus from integration you can smell bad code as well.

Comment: I've removed the comments below this answer as they are not needed anymore. Probably best to do the same. This comment will self destruct.

Comment: @tbking `new Buffer(key)` gives a deprecated warning. `(node:11772) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or
Buffer.from() methods instead.`

Comment: @Toheeb yes, use can use `Buffer.from(key)` instead or ignore the warning. :)